# variable declaration in modal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new to JS and Jquery in general and i was just going through he source of modal.js and came across the following difficulty . i saw the following declaration for a variable .

```
var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate
```

now i have read about short circuiting in JS . i understand how the || and && short circuiting works . but some how i don't understand the above line , so i tried to analysis it .

so basically in bootstrap , there is also a JS file called transitions.js and it comes with its own set of method , so i guess the below line :

```
$.support.transition
```

is checking weather that file is included or if a method in that file is available .

now , we move on to the second condition I.E. `animate`

animated is set a few line above in the modal.js plugin code , with the below check .

```
var animate = this.$element.hasClass('fade') ? 'fade' : '';
```

so in the above conditional if `this.$element.hasClass('fade')` is true , animate will be true , otherwise animate , will be empty , which will inturn be false.

so coming back to my question , can somebody expalin the below line to me , when will doAnimate be true and when will it be false :

```
var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate  .
```

Thank you.

Alexander.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote , that encourages me to learn more :) , but if u can please answer my question too . TY